UserControl not filling parent control in WinUI
I'm trying to create a UserControl that stretches to fill the entire parent control in my UNO WinUI 3 app, but it only takes up the required amount of space to contain its child controls and nothing more. Here's my setup:
MainPage.xaml:
<Page x:Class="UserControlScaling.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:UserControlScaling"
      xmlns:utu="using:Uno.Toolkit.UI"
      xmlns:um="using:Uno.Material"
      xmlns:views="using:UserControlScaling.Views"
      Background="{ThemeResource BackgroundBrush}">
  <Grid BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2">
    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <views:ExampleControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</Page>


ExampleControl
<UserControl
    x:Class="UserControlScaling.Views.ExampleControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UserControlScaling.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="This button does absolutely nothing" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Content="This is a button" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>

This is what it looks like:
The UserControl bordered by a red rectangle only takes up a fraction of  the parent container.
I am expecting the UserControl to take up all the space available to it when I give it the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment "stretch".

You are wrapping the UserControl with the ContentControl. The ContentControl is stretched but not its content. So, you need to set both HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment to Stretch.
<Grid>
    <ContentControl
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <views:ExampleControl />
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>    


This didn't work but this did: <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"> <views:ExampleControl/> </ContentControl> It's probably just a type, can you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Isn't that the same code? or you want me to remove the Grid?

You're right, I didn't see the edit from 7 hours ago. My bad and thanks for solving my issue.
